# SMS messages are not being sent from Journeys

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobileconnect, sms

I have created a Journey that is triggered from my Salesforce Opportunity object.

Part of the Journey should send an SMS which I have created as an "Outbound - Interaction", using the test function on Mobile Connect the SMS does indeed actually work but no SMS is sent when the Contact has reached and and been accepted by the Journey, I know this because there are other actions before and after the SMS action which are complete.

SMS has not been sent, on the MobileConnect overview page the send numbers are still at 0.

Could anyone tell me how I would troubleshoot this to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several reasons an SMS may not have been sent:

- the contact has no phone number linked to it. Make sure the contact is linked through the contact key to a data extension that contains a phone number (field type = phone). You can check this

  - the contact has a phone number linked but the phone number is not in the correct format, i.e. it has no country code (it's worth reading these and following documentation pages: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_contacts.htm&type=5)
  - the SMS provider didn't send the message because the phone is out of network reach or turned off
  - the phone number does not have a subscription (keyword) linked to it needed to send the message. This you can do manually through contact builder or you can select an option to "force add" the contact to a keyword